# How to store array address within an index of another array?

Tags: c

Stored address of array at a index of another array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int *ip_range ;
int *new_ip_range ;

int main()
{
  //malloc a array.
  ip_range = (int ) malloc(2  sizeof(int));
  ip_range[0]=2;
  ip_range[10]=2;
  //malloc second array.
  new_ip_range = (int ) malloc(2  sizeof(int));
  ip_range[11] =new_ip_range[0]; //store the address of 1 array to another
  new_ip_range[0]=99;
  new_ip_range[1]=99;
  new_ip_range[2]=99;
  new_ip_range[3]=99;

  return 0;
}
```

I want to store address of  array(new_ip_range) in 11 index of array(ip_range).

Comment: `ip_range[11] =(int)(&new_ip_range[0])` or `ip_range[11] =(int)new_ip_range`

Comment: To compile, fix like this: `(int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int))`

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. To save the address of the array in another array you need an array of pointers.

Comment: @L_J Actually we have to split array and in previous array we want to store address of another array.  There is a possibility that we have to split second array further and stored the address of third array in last index of second array.

Comment: @Programmerdude **no**.

Comment: @ryyker *Why **no**, on either one of them? Both statements yield address.*  Neither of `ip_range[11] =(int)(&new_ip_range[0])` or `ip_range[11] =(int)new_ip_range` produces an address.  Both are `int` values.  `int` values **ARE NOT** addresses.  Period.  End of discussion.

Answer (score 1):

To store the address of an array in another array use the array of pointers as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int **ip_range;
int *new_ip_range;

int main()
{
    //malloc a array.
    ip_range = (int**)malloc(12 * sizeof(int*));

    //malloc second array.
    new_ip_range = (int*)malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    new_ip_range[0] = 99;
    new_ip_range[1] = 99;
    new_ip_range[2] = 99;
    new_ip_range[3] = 99;

    ip_range[11] = new_ip_range; //store the address of 1 array to another

    //printf("%d", ip_range[11][0]);

    free(new_ip_range);
    free(ip_range);

    return 0;
}
```